# Excel transpose formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, transpose

I've been wraping my head around it for some time and just don't know how to approach this problem. My table consists of groups of data which I want to transpose from rows to columns. Every row has an index number in first column and all of the rows in one group have the same index.

`1   a

1   b

1   c

1   d

1   e

1   f

1   g

1   h

2   as

2   bs

2   cs

5   ma

5   mb

5   mc

5   md`

and I want my final result to be:

`1  a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h

2   as  bs  cs

5   ma  mb  mc  md`

is it possible to do this with formulas or do I have to do it in VBA?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with formulas, but it's a bit difficult.

Comment: *jedi wave* `Transpose()` is not the function that you are looking for. I think that you want to set up a loop through your range(s) that looks for a value in Column A and then concatenates and prints the values in column B.

Comment: That's more of a Pivot than a Transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this using a macro.  Here is one method.

To enter this Macro (Sub), **alt-F11** opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this Macro (Sub), **alt-F8** opens the macro dialog box. Select the macro by name, and **RUN**.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReArrange()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, rSrc As Range
    Dim vRes As Variant, rRes As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim lColsCount As Long
    Dim Col As Collection
'Upper left cell of results
Set rRes = Range("D1")

'Assume Data in A1:Bn with no labels
Set rSrc = Range("a1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)

'Ensure Data sorted by index number
rSrc.Sort key1:=rSrc.Columns(1), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=rSrc.Columns(2), order2:=xlAscending, MatchCase:=False, _
    Header:=xlNo

'Read Source data into array for faster processing 
'  compared with going back and forth to worksheet
vSrc = rSrc

'Compute Number of rows = unique count of index numbers
'Collection object can only have one entry per key
'  otherwise it produces an error, which we skip
Set Col = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
    Col.Add Item:=vSrc(I, 1), Key:=CStr(vSrc(I, 1))
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'Compute Maximum Number of columns in results
'  Since there is one entry per Index entry, maximum number of
'  columns will be equal to the Index that has the most lines
'  So we iterate through each Index and check that.
For I = 1 To Col.Count
    J = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rSrc.Columns(1), Col(I))
    lColsCount = IIf(J > lColsCount, J, lColsCount)
Next I

'Set up Results array
'  Need to add one to the columns to account for the column with the Index labels
ReDim vRes(1 To Col.Count, 1 To lColsCount + 1)

'Now populate the results array
K = 1
For I = 1 To Col.Count
    vRes(I, 1) = vSrc(K, 1)
    J = 2
    Do
        vRes(I, J) = vSrc(K, 2)
        J = J + 1: K = K + 1
        If K > UBound(vSrc) Then Exit Do
    Loop Until vSrc(K, 1) <> vRes(I, 1)
Next I

'Set the results range to be the same size as our array
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1), columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))

'Clear the results range and then copy the results array to it
rRes.EntireColumn.Clear
rRes = vRes

'Format the width.  Could also format other parameters
rRes.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 10

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, it works like a charm. My only comment would be, if you could give a short explanation how it works.

Comment: I expanded the comments in my answer.  Basically we read the data into a variant array (faster to process an array in VBA than go back and forth to the worksheet).  Then we compute a unique list of Index numbers.  The results array will have one row for each index number, and as many columns as the Index with the most entries.  We compute that, create the array, and populate it; then write it to the results range.  You should read about the Collection object; and use the watch window and breakpoints to see the details of vSrc and vRes arrays.  Stepping through the macro would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. You would need the following functions:

1. IF
2. MATCH
3. ISNA
4. INDEX

Assume you have the data in sheet 1 in columns A and B:

[image]

**C1:**

place the value "1" in cell C1

**C2:**

=C1+1

drag down as much as needed

**D1**

```
=MATCH(C1,A:A, 0)
```

Drag down as much as cell C2

**E1**

```
=MATCH(C1,A:A, 1)
```

Drag down as much as cell C2

**Sheet 2:**
[image]

Now place the following formulas in cell A1 in sheet2:

```
=IF(ISNA(Sheet1!$D1), "", IF(Sheet1!$D1="", "", IF(COLUMN()-1+Sheet1!$D1 <=Sheet1!$E1, INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, COLUMN()-1+Sheet1!$D1), "")))
```

Drag / Copy it to as many cells as needed:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Also I have an article on my blog about the INDEX function. It might help [Excel INDEX Function](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/07/excel-index-function/).

You can also download the complete file [here](http://pedrumjalali.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/file.xlsx).