# Hide zero (0) values in INDEX formula

Tags: excel, formula

This is the follow-up question to ([Excel formula to transpose horizontal values in vertical list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54705558)). I have formula to display horizontally placed values in vertical table.

```
=INDEX($1:$1;(ROW(1:1)-1)*2+4)
=INDEX($1:$1;(ROW(2:2)-1)*2+4)
etc
```

The problem with current solution is that it is displaying (0) zero values if cells are empty. How I can modify this formula to hide all zero (0) values so it will give as a result `""`

In one column I have numbers and in other one text. So solution should be suitable for both or optionally two different approaches I can input to two different columns.

P.S. I do not want to hide zero values by Excel options, because I will use values further on and need them to be `=""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are retrieving text then just append a zero-length string.

```
=INDEX($1:$1;(ROW(1:1)-1)*2+4)&""
```

If you are retrieving something, it won't change the result. If there is nothing to return (blank) then nothing shows in the cell.

I don't recommend doing this when retrieving numbers or dates as it will change them to text.

Comment: I have text in one column and numbers in the other. How this can be implemented to situation where I have numbers?

Comment: Well, it can't. That's why I added the warning. The only way I know for numbers would be to check if the cell is blank first then either retrieve a number or supply a "".

Comment: If hiding all zero's wouldn't be a problem OP could also just use the inbuild option to hide zero's.

Comment: I know I can hide all zeros by Excel inbuild option but then I have a VBA macro for deleting empty rows. If cell is zero (0) it will still be a zero (just hided by Excel) and VBA macro does not recognize that. So I need cells to be "" instead of zero (0).

Comment: Maybe there is something to convert text cells back to numbers?

Comment: If you're getting rid of `""` with text to columns then numbers as text should convert to true numbers. tbh, you're pretty vague on specifics all around.

Comment: This seems to be the solution for numbers `=IFERROR(VALUE(INDEX($1:$1;(ROW(1:1)-1)*2+4)&"");"")`

Comment: but `value(<blank cell>)` is just another zero.

Comment: `=IFERROR(;"")` gives "" as a result and not zero. I need to have "" as a result in cells.